# Is it possible to start account authenticator activity from the abstractAccountAuthenticator

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have created an custom account application,Now when I use a third party application,in case of no account present,I would like to launch the login/Sign up activity from my application(my Custom Account Application).IS this possible?or do i have to pass the intent back to an accountManagerCallback and then launch an intent.

Essentially I would like to do all the handiwork within my application and return back to the the calling application only  with an access token.

And can someone explain to me the setAccountAuthenticatorResult(Bundle) method.Where does this return to?[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountAuthenticatorActivity.html#setAccountAuthenticatorResult(android.os.Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountAuthenticatorActivity.html#setAccountAuthenticatorResult%28android.os.Bundle%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution involved invalidating the current token.This would force my `AccountAuthenticatorActivity` to gain control which could then handle the situation as required.